# Angular 2 - PrimeNg style not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I've followed the instruction to install primeng by running `npm install primeng --save` then importing what I need in the `app.module.ts` file, for example:

```
import {CheckboxModule} from 'primeng/primeng';  

...

imports: [
    CheckboxModule,
  ],...
```

I then add the style sheets to the index.html file:

```
<head>
  ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
```

My IDE can find the file location (by holding ctrl and clicking on the href value) but it is not found by the browser (404 error).

I've copied the checkbox example (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) and added it to one of my components but the style is the same as a normal checkbox.

Also, no other errors are thrown.

Should the styles be added to another file?  I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: are you using **src** and **dist** folders to separate the code files? also what is issue when you followed this? checkbox didn't appear or styles are missed

Comment: @Aravind - I'm not using the dist folder,  the code is all within the src.  The checkboxes appear on the page but there is no styling applied (just plain checkboxes).  The error I get is 404 in chrome, e.g. `GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css `.  I get this for all the three stylesheets, even though I can actually locate the files manually in `app_module`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a [tutorial](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2016/10/27/primeng-with-angular-cli.html) that uses PrimeNg with Angular CLI that worked for me.

I added the `font-awesome.min.css` stylesheet to index.html.

Then the theme I wanted (e.g. `"../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",`) to angular-cli.json file in the `"styles" [...]` section.

Answer (score 14):

I resolve my problem by remove `rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"` from index.html and also added below imports to styles.css :

```
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

Answer (score 11):

in the `style.css` file , add your imports 
for example :

```
 @import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css'
```

### if you have correctly downloaded PrimeNG, it should work now

just a bit note : be sure you have imported the primeNG modules in the correct place (In fact, we import modules not components, take care;)

Comment: If you are not using the Angular CLI, you can include a prebuilt theme via a <link> element in your index.html

Comment: Strangely this solution worked for me, although I followed exactly the setup page why, am I doing something wrong to have only this solution working for me especially that this line is mentionned nowhere in the documentation...?

Comment: This worked for me because I am using Angular 8. The chosen answer is valid for an earlier version of Angular and primeng.

Answer (score 11):

A lot has changed since the question was first asked (in 2017) wrt the way themes (free and commercial) are available with `primeng`. This is updated answer for anyone facing a similar issue as above in 2020. (update valid for `"primeng": "^10.0.0-rc.2"` and `angular v~10.0.6`)

Essentially there are three ways of importing free `primeng` themes in an `angular 2+` application.

- add the `primeng` imports to `angular.json` styles block

```
  "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
            ],
```

- add primeng import to `src/app/styles.scss` file

```
@import url("../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-orange/theme.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");
```

- also you could link the styles in the html head tag but the issue there is that none of the paths from `/node_modules` work, so the way to make that work is to copy the styles (from say `/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-purple/theme.cs`s to an equivalent path in `/assets` and use that path in the link) - the possible issue why `/node_modules` links do not work is probably because angular compile process creates bundle files as part of the webpack workflow and does not affect the index.html in which the link is referenced to `/node_module`

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-link" type="text/css" href="assets/themes/saga-purple/theme.css">
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [**setup instructions**](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) you should use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

notice that the path starts with:

```
href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"
```

not:

```
href="../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just upgraded to PrimeNG 6.1.6 and got this error.

Looks like with this release the themes have stopped using theme.css in favor of theme.scss.  So, you will have to reference "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.scss" (instead of "theme.css") in the "styles" section of angular.json AND …

You will need to npm rebuild node-sass.

Comment: If you open theme.scss, you'll see the first line says, "Deprecated: Use nova instead". If you look, there's a theme called nova-light that contains a normal theme.css file.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for project structure if you are using cli you should add those to styles.css. In overall they should go into the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Add @imports in styles.css file

```
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "~primeflex/primeflex.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/fluent-light/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

for other themes, go to nodemoules/primeng/resources/themes and select themes