# Cannot apply `omega/theme.css` in angular.json

Tags: css, angular, primeng

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",  
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" //wont work
            ]
```

**omega/theme.css** always shows :-

> ERROR in multi
>   ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
>   ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css
>   ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css
>   ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'

I also tried to import this in style.css but no change. No error in any thing else.
I also installed:-

`npm install primeng font-awesome
npm install @angular/animations --save`

Is priming licensed or not?

Comment: 'Url' issue  You can find help here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012329/angular-2-primeng-style-not-working`

Comment: That theme is no long a part of the primeng package. They removed it several months ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - PrimeNg style not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012329/angular-2-primeng-style-not-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omega theme is not available.Because Deprecate all free themes and remove them in PrimeNG 7.0

Introduce a new Nova free theme generated by the PrimeNG Theme Designer to give free themes a premium look, Nova has 3 alternatives;

- nova-light
- nova-colored
- nova-dark

Use above themes.

Comment:  correct but there is also other theme lunu and rhea